# private method `select' called for #<Room:0x00000001f6f5f8> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, select, methods

I'm quite new to Ruby and I'm having trouble finishing an exercise I am trying to solve. It's a classic Game of Rooms, and after a messing a bit I've came up with a code that looked OK to me - minus that does not work.

I am trying to call the select method from within another method in a class, on what I am pretty sure it's an array (@position), but I'm getting the above error message.

Here's a sample of my code, any idea on why that .select is private will be welcome!

```
class GameofRooms
  attr_accessor :position

  def initialize
    @rooms = [ 
      Room.new("Red",{"s" => "Green", "e" => "Blue"},"it's a red room"),
      Room.new("Blue",{"w" => "Red", "e" => "Patio", "s" => "Yellow"},"it's a blue room"),
      Room.new("Yellow",{"e" => "Patio", "n" => "Blue", "w" => "Green"},"it's a yellow room"),
      Room.new("Green",{"n" => "Red", "e" => "Yellow"},"it's a green room"),
      Room.new("Patio",{"s" => "Green", "w" => "Blue"},"lovely garden")
    ]
    @position = @rooms[0]    
  end


  def get_input_move
    puts "Where would you like to go?"
    @input = gets.chomp
    if @position.exits.key?(@input)
      roomName = @position.exits[@input]
      room = @position.select {|selectedRoom| selectedRoom.name == roomName } 
      self.class.move(room)
    elsif 
      puts "You can't go in that direction"         
    end
  end

  def self.move(room)
    @position = room
    @position.each do |room|
      puts "You have entered the #{name} room. #{text}" 
    end
  end
end

class Room
  attr_accessor :name, :exits, :text

  def initialize(name,exits,text="")
    @name = name
    @exits = exits
    @text = text
  end
end

round = GameofRooms.new
round.get_input_move
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `select` on an object of type Room, not an array. It is just one room because this line

```
@position = @rooms[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`select`'s receiver is `@position`, which is an instance of `Room`. Let's have a look at that method:

```
Room.instance_method(:select)
  #=> #<UnboundMethod: A(Kernel)#select>
Room.private_instance_methods.include?(:select)
  #=> true 
Room.public_instance_methods.include?(:select)
  #=> false
```

This tells us the at method is unbound (and comes from the module `Kernel`, namely [Kernel#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-select)) and `private`, the latter accounting for the error message received.

`Kernel#select` is not the method desired. That's because `select`'s receiver is incorrect. I expect you want [Array#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-select), which would be compatible with `@rooms`, but I don't know if the code is otherwise correct.